# Is a sequence convergent if it is bounded and a combination of a monotone increasing and decreasing sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

If a bounded sequence is the sum of a monotone increasing and a monotone decreasing sequence ($x_n=y_n+z_n$ where ${y_n}$ is monotone increasing and ${z_n}$ is monotone decreasing) does it follow that the sequence converges?

Comment: The difference of non-decreasing bounded sequences is a sequence of bounded variation. The converse is also valid. That's the best result in this direction that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

No. Check these $x_n = (-1)^n, y_n = 2^n +(-1)^n, z_n = -2^n $.

Comment: $x_n$ is bounded, and $y_n, z_n$ need not be bounded in given assumption, just monotonicities.

Comment: You're right, my mistake.